CubeJS Refresh Worker Error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'environment)
We have a cubeJS deployment in ECS. Deployment consists of an API, a CubeJS backend, two cubestore containers (Router and worker), and a refresh worker.
Unfortunately, we are receiving the following error when the Refresh worker is called to perform a refresh:
{"message":"Refresh Scheduler Error","error":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'environment')\n at CubejsServerCore.contextToAppId (/usr/src/app/index.js:5:62)\n at CubejsServerCore.getCompilerApi (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/server-core/src/core/server.ts:490:30)\n at RefreshScheduler.runScheduledRefresh (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/server-core/src/core/RefreshScheduler.ts:281:49)\n at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)\n at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)\n at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)","securityContext":{},"requestId":"scheduler-763fcbf2-5f2f-43f3-9c50-550e70df889b"}

Looking at the cube code, it is attempting to set the 'environment' variable from authInfo:
const CubejsServer = require('@cubejs-backend/server');
const SqlDriver = require('@cubejs-backend/mysql-driver');
 
const server = new CubejsServer({
    contextToAppId: ({ authInfo }) => `CUBEJS_APP_${authInfo.environment}`,
    driverFactory: ({ authInfo }) =>
        new SqlDriver({
            database: `ap_${authInfo.environment}`
            //database: `ap_dev`
        })
});
 
server.listen().then(({ version, port }) => {
    console.log(` Cube.js server (${version}) is listening on ${port}`);
}).catch(e => {
    console.error('Fatal error during server start: ');
    console.error(e.stack || e);
});

This is where my understanding of the issue falls apart. I don't think I understand how cube is sourcing the info it's trying to pull from authInfo, nor why it is not being passed properly from the main cube backend to the refresh worker.
Happy to provide whatever other information needed to figure out what's going on.
